# In FROM scratch, which user is executing the file?

Tags: docker

My goal is to build an image with `FROM scratch` and to know which user is executing the file, maybe with `whoami`, and to check the file permission, maybe with `ls -l`.

The problem are, `FROM scratch` don't have `whoami` or `ls -l`. Installing the `busybox` throws error as well.

The surprising thing is, that I still can do `USER` after `FROM scratch`. I just can't choose any user.

What I've did:

1. Create non-root user and do `COPY --from=0 /etc/passwd /etc/passwd` it to the next layer and do `USER nonroot`
2. Download busybox binary and do `ENTRYPOINT ["/busybox"]`

It throws error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/busybox": permission denied: unknown
```

Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

## Build
# Alpine is chosen for its small footprint
# compared to Ubuntu
FROM golang:1.19-alpine

WORKDIR /app

# Download necessary Go modules
COPY go.mod ./
# COPY go.sum ./
# RUN go mod download

COPY *.go ./

RUN go build -o /main

RUN adduser \
    -h "/dev/null" \
    -g "" \
    -s "/sbin/nologin" \
    -D \
    -H \
    -u 10001 \
    playerone

## Deploy
FROM scratch

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=0 /main /main

COPY --from=0 /etc/passwd /etc/passwd

USER playerone

ENTRYPOINT [ "/main" ]
```

main.go

```
package main

import "log"

func main() {
    log.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

go.mod

```
module github.com/kidfrom/learn-golang/docker-scratch

go 1.19
```

Comment: I don't see `busybox` anywhere in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Please see [mcve].

Comment: @JohnKugelman ah sorry, I just do `ADD busybox.tar.xz /` and then `ENTRYPOINT ["/busybox"]`

Comment: @BMitch sorry, I will add the `go.mod` and `main.go`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you provided runs for me.

```
$ docker run --rm test-go-scratch
2022/09/10 19:17:55 Hello World!
```

Changing `FROM scratch` to `FROM busybox` allows me to run:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/sh test-go-busybox
/ $ id
uid=10001(playerone) gid=10001 groups=10001
```

showing that the container is configured to run as the requested user.

To see that is still happening in scratch, I changed to `main.go` to:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    uid := os.Getuid()
    gid := os.Getgid()
    log.Printf("Hello World! uid=%d, gid=%d", uid, gid)
}
```

And running that outputs the expected:

```
$ docker run --rm test-go-scratch
2022/09/10 19:23:42 Hello World! uid=10001, gid=10001
```

Comment: `os.Getuid()` and `os.Getgid()` is the solution. Without `USER 10001:10001`, the stdout will be `uid=0,gid=0` which is the id for root.

Comment: Anyway, is it safe to run scratch image with `uid=0,gid=0`?

Comment: @kidfrom it depends on your threat model and your docker engine configuration. If your engine is running rootless, probably. If you are worried about a malicious container exploiting the next runc CVE, maybe not. If you map host folders into the container with a volume, root in the container is root in that mapped directory.

Comment: I tested it by doing `$ docker create testvolume` -> add a go binary to run, chmod it the file to `754` / other can't execute the file. Then, mount it to the scratch image. If I execute the go binary from the volume without `USER 10001:10001`, the file will be executed. So, in my case, it probably pose a security riisk.

Comment: I heard that mounting host directory to container is not the docker idiomatic way, so I will use `docker volume`. Anyway, is rootless docker engine necessary or running an image with nonroot user is enough?

Comment: @kidfrom that also depends on your threat model. Are you worried about a process escaping the container? Then running the container with a non-root user should be good. If you're worried about the user running the containers running a malicious container, then you probably don't want them with access to the docker daemon running as root. This is all degrees of risk and attack scenarios you want to defend against.

Comment: `If you're worried about the user running the containers running a malicious container` > Do you mean by `user`, you mean the `linux user`? e.g a linux user do `$ sudo docker run -it redis` and it turns out `redis` is malicious. Is `docker run -u 10001:10001` sufficient to solve this threat model or rootless docker engine is the only solution?

Comment: @kidfrom the user on the host that has access to the docker CLI. The CLI that could run `docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i bash` to escalate from their user to root on the host.